# log rules for MLE

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Does anyone know how I get from,

$$\ln\left\{\frac{1}{\sigma}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right\}$$

To

$$-\frac{1}{2}\ln{\sigma^2-}\frac{1}{2}\ln2\pi$$

Comment: Use the logarithm laws $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$ , $\ln(\frac{a}{b})=\ln(a)-\ln(b)$ and $\ln(a^r)=r\cdot \ln(a)$

Comment: im really struggling with this peter, I know these laws but can I get there using them?

Comment: Well, you have a product, so what is the first step ?

Comment: Maybe it would help to point out the typo, pretty sure it should be $-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi)$

Comment: @Michael Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @Micheal thanks

Comment: $$ln(1/\sigma)+ln(1/\sqrt(2\pi))$$

Comment: $$ln(\sigma^{-1})+ln((2\pi)^{-1/2})$$

Comment: A good start. Now, apply the rule for the powers.

Comment: $$-ln(\sigma)+-1/2ln((2\pi))$$//

Comment: This is where I get stuck, is it possible

Comment: Only the base must be positive, the exponent can be negative. So yes, you can apply it. For the last step, consider $\ln(\sigma^2)=2\cdot \ln(\sigma)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77019/discussion-between-zarina-akhtar-and-peter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from you,
\begin{align}
-\ln(\sigma)-\frac12\ln(2\pi)&=-\ln\left((\sigma^2)^{\frac12}\right)-\frac12\ln(2\pi)\\
&=-\frac12\ln\sigma^2-\frac12\ln2\pi
\end{align}

Comment: I am a student and helping me means a lot.